# Android toolbar home/up indicator unread count

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a master/detail view and I need to add an unread count to the "up/home/back" button. I've added unread counts to other toolbar items using app:actionlayout, but I don't see that being useful in this case.

I believe I will need to get a reference to the home/up menu item, and add a view to it. If this is the case, I need to get a reference to the menu item, something I am so far unsuccessful doing. Is there another technique for this?

Comment: you question is not clear enough to give a solution. also add some code you tried so far. plz make a clear sense about what you want to achieve

Comment: On the application toolbar, I want to add an element that overlays the home button. This element would be a square block of color that contains a number. I would then dynamically change the number and toggle the visibility of the element as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try my implementation, looks like this[image: notification with counter example]

Code for details fragment:

```
      final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            final Drawable icon = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
            if (icon != null) {
                if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                    final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrw = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                    final OverlayDrawable overlay = new OverlayDrawable(getResources(), bitmapDrw.getBitmap());
                    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(overlay);
                    overlay.setCount(1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Drawable code:

```
public class OverlayDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

private final Paint mPaintCircle;
private final Paint mPaintText;

private int mCount = 0;
private final Rect mTextBounds;

public OverlayDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(res, bitmap);

    mPaintCircle = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintCircle.setColor(Color.RED);

    mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mTextBounds = new Rect();

}

public void setCount(int count) {
    mCount = count;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    float minSize = Math.min(getIntrinsicWidth(), getIntrinsicHeight());
    float radius = minSize / 3.0f;
    float x = getIntrinsicWidth() - radius / 2;
    float y = minSize / 4.0f;
    mPaintText.setTextSize(1.5f * radius);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mPaintCircle);

    final String text = Integer.toString(mCount);
    mPaintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), mTextBounds);

    canvas.drawText(text, x - mTextBounds.width() / 2.0f - mTextBounds.left - 1, y + mTextBounds.height() / 2.0f, mPaintText);
}

}
```